# Problem with dependencies in code (streamlit)

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm trying to run this code in my Python3.6:

https://github.com/icedevil2001/mark_minervini_stock_screener/blob/main/stock_screener.py

I've installed all the packages but I still get this error:

```
"C:\Users\...\Python @Market\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/.../Desktop/Python @Market/Minervini_Screener.py"
Warning - Certain functionality 
             requires requests_html, which is not installed.
             
             Install using: 
             pip install requests_html
             
             After installation, you may have to restart your Python session.
2022-07-10 17:52:51.988 
  Warning: to view this Streamlit app on a browser, run it with the following
  command:

    streamlit run C:/Users/.../Python @Market/Minervini_Screener.py [ARGUMENTS]
```

How do I execute Streamlit in app or browser?  I've tried this in my console:

```
streamlit run Minervini_Screener.py
```

But returns an error.

```
“‘streamlit’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.”
```

Thanks team!

Answer (score 0):

Try typing this on your console:

`py -m streamlit run ".../path/file.py"`